# message": "Invalid method %1::%2

Tags: magento2

[image]

I suddenly started getting this error when i run api on postman.Can anyone help me?

Comment: try this url `http://127.0.0.1:8888/magentoshop/rest/<storecode>/V1/get_products`

Comment: I think It's your custom api, check your method : "GET" it's correct or not by your webbapi.xml file.